# Append filtered options array to select: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

Tags: jquery, filter, append

The below code is a slightly truncated version of what I'm working with, for brevity: hopefully it's enough to illustrate the problem. I can set up a jsfiddle if it'll help?

Anyhow: I'm creating an array of jquery  objects, then filtering out any whose value is in an array of already-selected values, then trying to append the result to my select box.

I think the problem lies in what I'm getting back from the filter() operation. It's showing up as an array of objects, but each object starts "e.fn.e.init[1]". When I try to append that array of objects to the select box, I get **NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8**

```
var selected_roles = [2,4],
all_roles = [];

// these lines generated from PHP
all_roles.push( $('<option value="3">Doctor</option>') );
all_roles.push( $('<option value="4">Dentist</option>') );
all_roles.push( $('<option value="2">Biscuit Designer</option>') );
all_roles.push( $('<option value="7">International Playboy</option>') );


function getAvailableRoleOptions(){
    var out = all_roles;
    return out.filter( function(element) {
        return $.inArray( parseInt( $(element).attr('value') ), selected_roles ) === -1;
    });
}

$options = getAvailableRoleOptions();

$('#job_select').empty().append( $options );
```

What is the filter function returning to me? Do I need to use get() somewhere, and if so, where? Can I even do what I'm trying to? Am I going about this all wrong? :)

Thanks :)